# ERROR [Vue warn]: option "el" can only be used during instance creation with the `new` keyword

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have the following abbreviated vue component:

```
    <template>
    <section>
        <v-card class="mx-auto" color="#26c6da" dark max-width="1200">
        <v-carousel >
            <v-carousel-item v-for="(item,i) in items" :key="i" v-html="item.content"> </v-carousel-item>
        </v-carousel>
        </v-card>
    </section>
    </template>


    <script>
    ...........................
    console.log(res);
    export default {
        el: '#app',
        data: function() {
        return {
            items: res
        };
        }
    };
    </script>

    <style scoped>
    #app iframe {
        width: 100%;
        height: 500px;
    }
    </style>
```

I want to add the css at the bottom to control the carousel appearance. To do this I tried to declare the 'el' property and hang the css on that. I;m getting the error in the title. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not need `el: '#app',` in your component. That is only used when initiating a new Vue app.

Further your css will automagically be scoped to that component instance per your scoped attribute on the style tag.

If the Iframe is nested in another compnent you will need to use the deep selector:

```
<style scoped>
    /deep/ iframe {
        width: 100%;
        height: 500px;
    }
</style>
```

https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error while unit testing with Jest.

This code here below was throwing the error during the unit test of `App.vue`:

**~/app.js**

```
import App from '~/components/App.vue';

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    store,
    ...App,
});
```

**~/components/App.vue**

```
export default {
    el: '#app', // remove this to fix a redundant-declaration error

    // ...
}
```

The solution was to remove the redundant `el` declaration in `App.vue`. In retrospect, this makes sense because `el` was declared twice, and the second time was via `...App,` when the component was spread into the new app in `app.js` (note: app.js runs first with respect to time).

In my case, it wasn't instantly obvious because the spread operation was obfuscating the redundant declaration. It required the analysis of two files to see it.

The app actually did work, but Jest caught the error during the unit test.